# How to connect an EmberJS front-end with an NodeJS Express API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, ember.js

I'm working on a MEEN-stack (MySQL, EmberJS, Express, and NodeJS) project.  I have never worked with Ember at all.  My only front-end experience is jQuery.

The project is separated into folders, with the front-end (Ember) in one folder and the Express API in another.  Front-end will handling loading in web-pages while sending requests to Express API for database requests / authentication / more.

I am currently able to connect the two servers via an explicit URL with jQuery's Ajax method in a webpage's static javascript file (along with allowing CORS and modifying the Ember environment file in app/config).

My confusion is that there is definitely a more elegant solution for connecting the two, but I'm lost on how to go about it.

From looking at tutorials, I have attempted adding an application.js file in the Ember Front-End app/adapters folder:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:9029',
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

But I don't have the knowledge to fully implement it or test it.  What am I missing?  How do I take advantage of the adapter file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start ember use:

```
ember server --proxy 'http://localhost:9029'
```

Assuming that you node server is serving your api from `http://localhost:9029` as you start the ember server with the proxy the `ember-cli` will spin up a very simple node proxy that will proxy your requests while you are developing.

Then you can remove the host from your `adapter.js` file

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

Also if you want brevity:

```
ember s -pxy 'http://<YOUR LOCAL SERVER AND PORT>'
```

Comment: Nice! that did it.

Note from your original post:
I've encountered this error in my iterm when I tried implementing.

FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc()

I had to restart my Macbook (Yosemite) since the error kept happening even with just ember s

The edit you made was able to fulfill what I wanted.

Any reason for that?

Also, now that the namespace is established, what ways are there to make calls to the express API rather than just jQuery calls in static js files?